# Can I get an automatic notification from Amazon Mechanical Turk when my batch is done?

Tags: mechanicalturk

Is it possible to get some automatic notification (e.g. mail) when a batch that I uploaded as a requester to AMT is completed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to configure it via the API. You can configure a ["HITTypeNotification"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_SetHITTypeNotificationOperation.html) which will send you an email whenever a HIT becomes "reviewable" (i.e., whenever it is complete). You can also trigger these notifications to be sent to an Amazon SQS Queue instead.

Note: This applies to a "HITType", not a batch, so you will receive a separate notification for each HIT in the batch (not each assignment, but each HIT or line in the uploaded CSV).